# Pass values from JQUERY to PHP then output to INPUT in FORM

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

i need to get a value from the a form then send it to php using jquery then output the result a dropdown select menu

get the value of using jquery

```
 <input id="search" name="search" type="text">
```

send it to php and perform a query

```
  <select  id="farmertype" name="farmertype" >

         <option value="" > - PLEASE SELECT FARM -</option>

         ////   output here as options                                      
  </select>
```

my php file farm.php

```
<?php
include_once("../init.php");
$q = ($_POST["search"]);

$db->query("SELECT * FROM farmers ");
  while ($line = $db->fetchNextObject()) {

      $idno = $line->idno;
      echo "<option value='$idno'>$idno</option>";

   }
 }

?>
```

the jquery part is so messy this is where i really need help

```
$("#search").click(function() {
    search = $(this).attr('#search');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'farm.php',
        data: "#search=" + search,

    });
});
```

Comment: [saw a question just like this earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415678/pass-values-from-jquery-to-php-then-output-to-input-in-form) but [from another account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3804415/dannjoroge) and was deleted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yet this one managed to get 2 upvotes and 2 favourite!!

Comment: @Steve and they think they can truly *hide* ;-) hah - I guess some just can't take the pressue. *Hm...* upvotes,... from who's "account"?

Comment: thanks let me try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it will help you.

JQuery:

```
$("#search").click(function() {
    search = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'farm.php',
        data: {searchValue:search},
        success:function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    include_once("../init.php");
    $q = ($_POST["searchValue"]);
    $db->query("SELECT * FROM farmers");
    $result = [];
    while ($line = $db->fetchNextObject()) {
        $idno = $line->idno;
        $result = "<option value='$idno'>$idno</option>";
    }
    print_r($result);
?>
```

what is the purpose of your variable $q?

Comment: this one works. how do i output the result to a particular id in the form

Comment: $('#id').text(result[array_index]) if you need to replace a text or $('#id').val(result[array_index]) if you need to replace a value

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery can be like :

```
$("#search").click(function() {
    search = $('#search').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'farm.php',
        data: {search : search},
        success: function(html){
            alert(html);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('#search');` Whats that?? Also, the php file specifies a POST request (though it never uses it).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#search").click(function() { /* I think you should use keyUp or use click on a button, nobody clicks an input box */
var search = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST', // 
    url: 'farm.php',
    data: {'search' : search},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }

});
```

});

Comment: the php file specifies a POST request (though it never uses it)